# How do you subscribe to push notifications in microsoft graph?

Tags: https, push-notification, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-teams

I have been trying to figure out how to use the beta [notifications](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/notifications-api-overview?view=graph-rest-beta) resource to send push notifications to users in Teams, but I cannot get past step 1.

> User signs in to your application, which creates a subscription with the Microsoft Graph notification service.

I am not using a language with Microsoft library support so I cannot use their SDKs. Instead, I am manually sending http requests. I have tried many, but I can't even nail down what the "resource" is supposed to be in the [subscription](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/subscription?view=graph-rest-beta) type. Here are some of the things I have tried and the results:

Sending this message:

```
{
    "changeType": "created",
    "notificationUrl": "https://(...)/notifications",
    "resource": "me/notifications",
    "expirationDateTime": "2020-11-04T18:23:45.9356913Z"
}
```

Results in:

```
{
    "error": {
        "code": "InvalidRequest",
        "message": "Subscription for resource 'me/notifications' is not supported.",
        "innerError": {
            "date": "2020-11-04T17:12:24",
            "request-id": "66172d3c-298d-47d4-babb-52d96ef42179",
            "client-request-id": "1c20849c-fcda-0b07-56e3-5bed08bb28e4"
        }
    }
}
```

The above message also correctly calls my server's /notifications route with this param:

```
Validation: Testing client application reachability for subscription Request-Id: 2f3cc3b8-b2c2-5922-451c-433add43bc74
```

Sending this one:

```
{
    "changeType": "created",
    "notificationUrl": "https://(...)/notifications",
    "resource": "notification",
    "expirationDateTime": "2020-11-04T18:23:45.9356913Z"
}
```

Results in:

```
{
    "error": {
        "code": "BadRequest",
        "message": "Resource not found for the segment 'notification'.",
        "innerError": {
            "date": "2020-11-04T17:21:15",
            "request-id": "d894c93b-9dac-4051-a3af-cb6039f1394b",
            "client-request-id": "84d18ec7-2c67-8240-b576-03641b3b5a59"
        }
    }
}
```

I have also tried "notifications", "users/me/notifications", and a few others to no avail. What's the deal, Microsoft? This resource isn't even listed under the possible subscription types in the beta docs, so is it supported or not?

Comment: Where exactly you want to send to? If It's just MS Teams you can use "Teams chatmessage" notification url in the page [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/webhooks?view=graph-rest-beta). You can also explore webhooks that could serve similar purpose [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/webhooks-and-connectors/how-to/connectors-using).

Comment: I need to create a push notification which will direct users to the custom app in teams. The chat message notification is not used this way from what I can tell. It does not create chat messages, but notifies a web service on changes/updates/deletes of chat messages, which is not what I want. Webhooks look almost right, but I don't want to configure them for a teams channel, which is the only available option.

Comment: Where exactly do you see that Notifications can be used to push TO Teams? From what I'm reading, it will push ABOUT messages in Teams, but not that Teams can be a 'destination', so to speak, if that's what you're trying to do?

Comment: That is definitely a big part of the confusion about this whole topic. Searching for notifications in teams predictably returns the wrong kind. However, this page (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/notifications-post?view=graph-rest-beta#permissions) is pretty clear: 

Create and send a notification targeting a user through Microsoft Graph. The notification is stored in the Microsoft Graph notification feed store, and is sent to all app clients on all device endpoints that the user is signed in to.

Also, the request contains targets such as "Windows", "ios", "Android".

Comment: I suggest that the common user and design terminology for 
- 'Notifications' sent to a user is **'Alerts'**
- and **'change notifications'** are the things that are that sent to an app using 'subscriptions'

Comment: The docs seem very confusing to me as well, totally agree. The way _I'm_ reading it, it's not clear that it sending notifications TO Teams, rather ABOUT Teams. It mentions that the notifications can be sent on all media/devices, but not where/how they arrive (is it a Teams message, or is it just a push notification of some other sort...)

Comment: I see this documentation added recently.See if this helps https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/teams-changenotifications-chatMessage

Comment: That documentation refers to the other kind of notifications (change notifications), and does not provide any info on subscribing to push notifications.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At this point I'm pretty sure this functionality just doesn't work/exist.